# Angular: Acceder a un objeto de profundidad

Tags: json, angular, typescript, objeto, javascriot

Estaba trabajando en Angular, queria acceder a un objeto pero me dice que viene indefinido, cuando obtengo la respuesta e incluso use el operador '?' para evitar errores no entiendo que esta pasando

Mire este es el get en mi servicio

```
  getRoomInfo(params: string){
    return this.http.get<Room>(environment.api_URL + `appointments/${params}/getInfo-room`);
  }
```

Como ven le paso el tipado de este, ajá y este es el objeto en donde quiero obtener la res de la peticion. Este es la interfaz que hice (quicktipe):

```
export interface Room {
    infoRoom: InfoRoom
}
export interface InfoRoom {
    _id:                string;
    medicalAppointment: MedicalAppointment;
    affiliate:          Affiliate;
    channelId:          string;
    roomId:             string;
    appId:              string;
    customer:           Customer;
    time:               Date;
    createdAt:          Date;
    updatedAt:          Date;
    __v:                number;
}

export interface Affiliate {
    insurances:          any[];
    officePhone:         string[];
    enabled:             boolean;
    active:              boolean;
    approved:            boolean;
    degree:              Degree[];
    certificateCollege:  any[];
    currency:            string;
    timezone:            string;
    isTopDokto:          boolean;
    appointmentsFromApp: boolean;
    rating:              number;
    feedbackCount:       number;
    maxOverbooking:      number;
    commission:          number;
    _id:                 string;
    firstName:           string;
    lastName:            string;
    fullName:            string;
    email:               string;
    name:                string;
    vid:                 number;
    affiliateType:       string;
    country:             string;
    attachments:         any[];
    createdAt:           Date;
    updatedAt:           Date;
    __v:                 number;
    address:             string;
    cellPhone:           string;
    gender:              string;
    identification:      string;
    rtn:                 string;
    specialty:           string;
    yearsExperience:     number;
    etag:                string;
    image:               string;
    previewLink:         string;
    socialDescription:   string;
    socialTitle:         string;
    urlShort:            string;
    userName:            string;
    otherEspecialty:     string;
    id:                  string;
}

export interface Degree {
    fieldname:    string;
    originalname: string;
    encoding:     string;
    mimetype:     string;
    size:         string;
    filename:     string;
    uuid:         string;
    name:         string;
    bucket:       string;
}

export interface Customer {
    cellPhone:         any[];
    officePhone:       any[];
    email:             string[];
    allergies:         any[];
    diseases:          any[];
    badHabits:         any[];
    enabled:           boolean;
    active:            boolean;
    completedProfile:  boolean;
    accountVerify:     boolean;
    verifiedCellphone: boolean;
    verifiedEmail:     boolean;
    _id:               string;
    firstName:         string;
    lastName:          string;
    username:          string;
    fullName:          string;
    userType:          string;
    country:           string;
    createdAt:         Date;
    updatedAt:         Date;
    __v:               number;
    birthDate:         Date;
    countryDetails:    CountryDetails;
}

export interface CountryDetails {
    callingCodes:   string[];
    _id:            string;
    name:           string;
    topLevelDomain: string[];
    alpha2Code:     string;
    alpha3Code:     string;
    capital:        string;
    altSpellings:   string[];
    region:         string;
    subregion:      string;
    population:     number;
    latlng:         number[];
    demonym:        string;
    area:           number;
    gini:           number;
    timezones:      string[];
    borders:        string[];
    nativeName:     string;
    numericCode:    string;
    currencies:     Currency[];
    languages:      Language[];
    translations:   Translations;
    flag:           string;
    regionalBlocs:  RegionalBloc[];
    cioc:           string;
    code:           number;
}

export interface Currency {
    code:   string;
    name:   string;
    symbol: string;
}

export interface Language {
    iso639_1:   string;
    iso639_2:   string;
    name:       string;
    nativeName: string;
}

export interface RegionalBloc {
    acronym:       string;
    name:          string;
    otherAcronyms: string[];
    otherNames:    string[];
}

export interface Translations {
    de: string;
    es: string;
    fr: string;
    ja: string;
    it: string;
    br: string;
    pt: string;
    nl: string;
    hr: string;
    fa: string;
}

export interface MedicalAppointment {
    status:            string;
    purpose:           string;
    contactEmail:      string[];
    contactPhone:      any[];
    service:           string[];
    paymentStatus:     string;
    enabled:           boolean;
    chargeFee:         boolean;
    reserveSlots:      boolean;
    _id:               string;
    draft:             boolean;
    pendingAction:     string;
    place:             string;
    affiliate:         string;
    patient:           string;
    items:             Item[];
    appointmentSource: string;
    start:             Date;
    end:               Date;
    symptom:           string;
    date:              Date;
    createdAt:         Date;
    updatedAt:         Date;
    __v:               number;
}

export interface Item {
    quantity: number;
    price:    number;
    tax:      number;
    _id:      string;
    category: string;
    service:  string;
}
```

Este es el json:

```
{
    "videoCallRoom": {
        "_id": "62a79271fa19bd3e1cf594c7",
        "medicalAppointment": {
            "status": "scheduled",
            "purpose": "consultation",
            "contactEmail": [
                ""
            ],
            "contactPhone": [],
            "service": [
                "5f88fc33596ccdbcee46fea9"
            ],
            "paymentStatus": "paid",
            "enabled": true,
            "chargeFee": true,
            "reserveSlots": true,
            "_id": "62a79271fa19bd3e1cf594c5",
            "draft": false,
            "pendingAction": "affiliate",
            "place": "5f88fc33596ccd81ce46fea5",
            "affiliate": "5f88fad8fbe0751540193757",
            "patient": "60f70f6a913cf44447b1605b",
            "items": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "price": 500,
                    "tax": 0,
                    "_id": "5f88fc33596ccdbcee46fea9",
                    "category": "5ebaeb1f8a63e8294a2f0b4e",
                    "service": "5ebae8f65d8a9e7bab97f59c"
                }
            ],
            "appointmentSource": "",
            "start": "2022-07-01T03:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2022-07-01T04:00:00.000Z",
            "symptom": "",
            "date": "2022-07-01T03:00:00.000Z",
            "createdAt": "2022-06-13T19:39:29.319Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-06-13T19:39:29.319Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "affiliate": {
            "insurances": [],
            "officePhone": [
                "+"
            ],
            "enabled": true,
            "active": true,
            "approved": true,
            "degree": [
                {
                    "fieldname": "file",
                    "originalname": "undefined/afd55c09-5976-4f2a-9549-6b1fa25d5a9d-Affiliate-degree-geo-app.postman-collection.json",
                    "encoding": "7bit",
                    "mimetype": "application/json",
                    "size": "2884",
                    "filename": "degree",
                    "uuid": "afd55c09-5976-4f2a-9549-6b1fa25d5a9d",
                    "name": "",
                    "bucket": "-documents"
                }
            ],
            "certificateCollege": [],
            "currency": "HNL",
            "timezone": "America/Tegucigalpa",
            "isTopDokto": false,
            "appointmentsFromApp": true,
            "rating": 4,
            "feedbackCount": 0,
            "maxOverbooking": 0,
            "commission": 16,
            "_id": "5f88fad8fbe0751540193757",
            "firstName": "Juan",
            "lastName": "Perez",
            "fullName": "Juan Perez",
            "email": "",
            "name": "La Cafe",
            "vid": 151251,
            "affiliateType": "5d242fc13555ec2b76e86bcd",
            "country": "HND",
            "attachments": [],
            "createdAt": "2020-10-16T01:43:52.183Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-06-09T17:35:10.134Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "address": "Jardines del Valle",
            "cellPhone": "99928583",
            "gender": "M",
            "identification": "0501199011757",
            "rtn": "05011990117573",
            "specialty": "Medicina General y Cirugia",
            "yearsExperience": 10,
            "etag": "\"f458b9417e2a60b472edc82a7a15d59c\"",
            "image": "h",
            "previewLink": "",
            "socialDescription": "Agenda tu cita con el Doctor Agenda tu cita con el DoctorAgenda tu cita con el DoctorAgenda tu cita con el tu cita con el t",
            "socialTitle": "Juan Perez",
            "urlShort": "",
            "userName": "juanperez1",
            "otherEspecialty": "Cirugia",
            "id": "5f88fad8fbe0751540193757"
        },
        "channelId": "62a79271fa19bd3e1cf594c5",
        "roomId": "62a79271fa19bd3e1cf594c5",
        "appId": "453bee4ca9fa4648bbe374f5237fc810",
        "customer": {
            "cellPhone": [],
            "officePhone": [],
            "email": [
                ""
            ],
            "allergies": [],
            "diseases": [],
            "badHabits": [],
            "enabled": true,
            "active": true,
            "completedProfile": false,
            "accountVerify": false,
            "verifiedCellphone": false,
            "verifiedEmail": false,
            "_id": "60f70f6a913cf44447b1605b",
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "Dev",
            "username": "",
            "fullName": "",
            "userType": "5cd51ff333d554e479daaee9",
            "country": "HND",
            "createdAt": "2021-07-20T18:01:14.975Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-07-20T20:09:23.923Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "birthDate": "1998-04-23T06:53:16.000Z",
            "countryDetails": {
                "callingCodes": [
                    "504"
                ],
                "_id": "5a63e334e05e270777521a16",
                "name": "Honduras",
                "topLevelDomain": [
                    ".hn"
                ],
                "alpha2Code": "HN",
                "alpha3Code": "HND",
                "capital": "Tegucigalpa",
                "altSpellings": [
                    "HN",
                    "Republic of Honduras",
                    "República de Honduras"
                ],
                "region": "Americas",
                "subregion": "Central America",
                "population": 8576532,
                "latlng": [
                    15,
                    -86.5
                ],
                "demonym": "Honduran",
                "area": 112492,
                "gini": 57,
                "timezones": [
                    "UTC-06:00"
                ],
                "borders": [
                    "GTM",
                    "SLV",
                    "NIC"
                ],
                "nativeName": "Honduras",
                "numericCode": "340",
                "currencies": [
                    {
                        "code": "HNL",
                        "name": "Honduran lempira",
                        "symbol": "L"
                    }
                ],
                "languages": [
                    {
                        "iso639_1": "es",
                        "iso639_2": "spa",
                        "name": "Spanish",
                        "nativeName": "Español"
                    }
                ],
                "translations": {
                    "de": "Honduras",
                    "es": "Honduras",
                    "fr": "Honduras",
                    "ja": "ホンジュラス",
                    "it": "Honduras",
                    "br": "Honduras",
                    "pt": "Honduras",
                    "nl": "Honduras",
                    "hr": "Honduras",
                    "fa": "هندوراس"
                },
                "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/hnd.svg",
                "regionalBlocs": [
                    {
                        "acronym": "CAIS",
                        "name": "Central American Integration System",
                        "otherAcronyms": [
                            "SICA"
                        ],
                        "otherNames": [
                            "Sistema de la Integración Centroamericana,"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "cioc": "HON",
                "code": 504
            }
        },
        "time": "2022-07-01T04:00:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2022-06-13T19:39:29.411Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-06-13T19:39:29.411Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

En react esto ya me habia pasado que no podia acceder a un atributo por mas que si existia, asi que hice uso de las operaciones ternarias algo asi: `res ? res.data : null`

Pero es que de ninguna de las dos formas me funciona y ya no se que otra forma pudiera hacerlo, tal vez que no estoy tratando la data como deberia

Comment: La raíz del JSON se llama `videoCallRoom` y la de la interfaz es `infoRoom`. Revisa eso porque los nombres deben ser iguales.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Siempre me trabo en cosas bien sencillas o que ya me habia topado antes